# Where to find resources on tablet heatmaps?

Tags: tablet, gestures, heatmaps

I need heatmaps on tablet usage to see what regions users make use of on tablets.

The reason that I need to do this is that I need to do a recommendation on what gestures I can use the best, to do certain actions on tablets (for example: closing articles with only your thumbs).

Any resources on that topic would be great as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure *usage* heat maps are all that useful, as users tend to interact with the regions where the most important controls are - regardless if they are in the optimum location or not.

There are some optimal thumb range heat maps in [an article about thumb reachability for different sized iPhones](http://scotthurff.com/posts/how-to-design-for-thumbs-in-the-era-of-huge-screens). It might be used with tablets as well by mirroring the heat map for two-handed use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm definitely going to use it.

Comment: Most people don't use their thumbs on a tablet unless it's a small one. They hold their tablet in 1 hand and use their index finger on the other hand to navigate. A heat map indicating thumb reachability does not reflect that usage.

Comment: Some interesting info (but based on a Surface): http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/BUILD2011/BPS-1004 @ 16:30

Comment: Usage will also be differ based on [app usage](http://news.designlanguage.com/post/1611663345). I don't think it's fair to ask for a global usage. Look for apps similar in layout/construction to yours and compare with their use cases.

Answer (score 0):

The IMB Design Language has a chapter on touch, specifically looking at tablets and it's various usage scenario's such as one hand, two hands, resting on lap, propped up etc.

Check out https://www.ibm.com/design/language/framework/interaction/touch